# drive selenium webdriver thru an xml- script is coded in java

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have very limited knowledge in Java and trying to create a script with Selenium Webdriver Java. My goal is to read data from an xml and use that data for my inputs(like username, password, server name etc). I am going thru different posts and i can read data and print it. But i am not sure how to use that data in Selenium sendkeys option.

I have a main class and i created a method to read an xml in that class. Here is the read function i created :-

```
public void readXml() throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        //Parsing of Book.xml is done here
        Document document = builder.parse(new File("C://Javaseleniumworld/Book.xml"));
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
//        double[] dataList = new double[100];
        NodeList node = document.getElementsByTagName("TestData");
//        NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("TestData Details");
        System.out.println("________________________________________________");


        for (int i = 0; i < node.getLength(); i++) {
            //We have encountered an <employee> tag.
            Node currentNode = node.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) currentNode;
                NodeList blocksserverElementList = element.getElementsByTagName("server");

//                   NodeList blocksServerElementList = element.getElementsByTagName("server");
                Element blocksServer = (Element) blocksserverElementList.item(0);
//               NodeList blocksServer1 = blocksServer.getChildNodes();
                String baseServer = ((Node) blocksServer).getNodeValue();
                System.out.println("Mail Servername:" + blocksServer);

                NodeList firstNameElementList = element.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
                Element firstName = (Element) firstNameElementList.item(0);
                NodeList FirstName = firstName.getChildNodes();
//                   String FirstName1 = ((Node) firstName.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                System.out.println("First Name:" + FirstName);
            }
        }
```

this is how my main class look

```
public class StartCaseJava extends TestCase {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    public static final String UserName = "something";
    public static final String Password = "something";
    //  Getting Date and Timestamp for Last Name
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyHHmmss");

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//        baseUrl = "something;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void testStartCaseJava() throws Exception {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String expectedTitle = "something";
        String actualTitle = "";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
        }
        else {
            this.getscreenshot("screenshot");
            this.closesomehting();
        }

//    Blocks Login
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("username_entry")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("username_entry")).sendKeys(StartCaseJava.UserName);
            driver.findElement(By.id("password_entry")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("password_entry")).sendKeys(StartCaseJava.Password);
            driver.findElement(By.id("gologin")).click();
        }
        catch (Exception e){ this.getscreenshot("screenshot");
            this.closevoynat();}
////            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.close")).click();
//               if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/span/input[2]"))) {
//               } else {
//                   this.getscreenshot("screenshot");
//                   this.closevoynat();
//               }
```

Comment: where have u identified the object so that u can use it? please show us ur test class with selenium side code

Comment: you should better create an array/arraylist and return that from your `readXml` method having the values you want to read from that xml.

Comment: So i have only one class and i am trying to create a readxml method in the same class.

Comment: just updated a part of my base class. I am a beginner in Java i think thats why i am struggling to use this method in the main class. Any suggestions would be appreciated